# Regex pattern to strip all the numeric characters from the URL (except for the version number)

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am programming something in Java and I need to "normalize" the URIs, meaning, treat a URI as unique regardless of the query parameter values for timestamp, portalId, timeout, app version, etc.

Here's my regex pattern:
(?<=/)[0-9]+

It works for the following URI:
https://app.url.com/user/1234567

However, it doesn't work for the URI below. Is it possible to have one Regex pattern to accommodate both scenarios?

https://api.url.com/logging/v1/log/analytics-multi/no-auth?clientSendTimestamp=1622719272795&id=863256543&clienttimeout=14000&hs_static_app=automation-ui&hs_static_app_version=1.3520

Comment: Just add the alternative, `(?<=/|some text here=)[0-9]+`

Comment: What is "etc"? _Any_ other query parameter? If so, can't you remove the query string completely?

Comment: What is the expected output for the second string? How can you describe the context where the numbers must get matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digits in the example seem to be after the `/` or the `=` as well as the `version=`

What you might do is matching 1 or more digits asserting either a `/` or `=` to the left, but not for example `version=` to the left.

```
(?<=[/=])(?<!version=)\d+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=[/=])` Positive lookbehind, assert either `/` or `+` directly to the left
- `(?<!version=)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `version=` directly to the left
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SI3Daf/1)

Answer (score 0):

To delete both trailing numeric id in the path and/or query params:

```
url = url.replaceAll("/\\d+\\b|\\?.*", "");
```